# Call .NET method according to database schedule

Tags: .net-core, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, hangfire, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm working on an application that allows users to define their own schedule for when a certain action will be performed. The action needs to be triggered at the scheduled time, and it will effectively call a method in my .NET Core application.

I've reviewed a number of recommended approaches, for example like this one, which discusses using an `IHostedService` - https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2017/08/01/building-a-scheduled-cache-updater-in-aspnet-core-2.html

I've also looked at [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/overview.html).

The issue with these approaches, and most of the discussion I've seen in other articles, is that they really focus on running tasks according to a pre-defined schedule (e.g. running a task every 2 hours), rather than a *custom, dynamic* schedule. I'm looking for an approach that explains how I can do something like continuously poll the database schedule from within the application (or do something equivalent, that's more efficient), in order to trigger an action.

What's an efficient way to check the database schedule and hook this up to something in my .NET Core app that can run the desired action at the scheduled time? Is there a way that either an `IHostedService` or HangFire can be used to do this? Are then any articles out there that provide a clear example of how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean with "define their own schedule" ? Is it something which can be translated to a CRON expression ? If so, Hangfire can handle it

Comment: @jbl - a user can specify a specific date/time for a pre-determined action to take place. The date/time is stored as part of a 'schedule' in the database. So something needs to be able to dynamically 'read' that schedule in order to call a method within the .NET Core application at the scheduled time.

Comment: The hangfire Schedule method seems to fit this need : https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/calling-methods-with-delay.html

Comment: Thanks @jbl. That still seems to be more geared toward jobs that need to be performed on a schedule, rather than calling a method at specified times. I'm looking at Coravel now, as it seems to fit my use case - https://docs.coravel.net/

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. So how we have handled something similiar in our team. We used a table which stored all the actions. For example to have those columns:

```
ActionId, UserId, Description, Timer, Priority, Recurring
```

Now we have a database where we store our actions. What I think you need is from this database to query the data correctly. For example:

```
ActionId, UserId, Description, Timer, Priority, Recurring
1           2          test      1        1        1
```

So using this you can actually read the data however you like and query actions that are to be executed. The above action will be executed every minute.

The reason we are using a database is because some actions may have a really long wait time for example like a week, so using a cache was not optimal.

So how to you read that data?

You create another small application (for scallability) that reads from the database as you define it to be. So basicly the workflow for your .net core app will be:

```
user creates task ----> .net core app saves it on database
```

And the workflow for your .net core console app which will read from the database:

```
define the timer to read the table ----> reads DB ----> calls your method
```

This approach of course is more hard-coded but in the same time it does not depend on another framework or library.